# Forest Admin is not updating fields after updating my models

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, forestadmin

Seems like sometimes updates the fields but other times doesn't. Cant't get the pattern or replicate the way of forcing the update.

Comment: Did you find any workaround? I don't get why it doesn't update.. Right after I save, the record get displayed, but not the updated version of it. As well for the database, the record doesn't get updated at all. I do the same as the doc, I am not sure to get it

Comment: I did not. Back then this was after a forest admin release improved and I was able to continue working without major issues. Has been a while since then so this is probably a different issue @Emixam23

Answer (score 1):

Can you check if your fields are updated after a few minutes? Maybe there's a short delay before seeing your updates in your admin.

Comment: I've realized that after a while the update is apply but seems inconsistent about when the updates will be there, makes a bit hard to customize the admin and play around. There is any way to force this update?